Issue with Filtering Data by Time Range in React Dashboard
I'm working on a React dashboard where I need to filter data by various time ranges (Day, Week, Month, Semester, Year). The challenge is to ensure the filtered data ends with the oldest data point available and starts from the beginning of the specified range.
However, when rendering the charts, I am encountering issues where the dates appear as Invalid Date. Here is a summary of my current approach:
const data = [
    { created_at: '2024-06-10T10:00:00Z', temperature: 25, humidity: 40 },
    { created_at: '2024-06-09T10:00:00Z', temperature: 26, humidity: 42 },
    // more data points...
];

I have a function to find the oldest data point:
const findOldestData = (data) => {
    if (!data || data.length === 0) return null;

    return data.reduce((oldest, record) => {
        const recordDate = new Date(record.created_at);
        return recordDate < oldest ? recordDate : oldest;
    }, new Date());
};

The filtering function:
const filterDataByRange = (data, range) => {
    if (!data || data.length === 0) return [];

    const now = new Date();
    const oldestDate = findOldestData(data);
    if (!oldestDate) return [];

    let startDate;

    switch (range) {
        case 'Dia':
            startDate = new Date(now);
            startDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
            break;
        case 'Semana':
            startDate = new Date(now);
            startDate.setDate(now.getDate() - 7);
            startDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
            break;
        case 'Mês':
            startDate = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), 1);
            startDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
            break;
        case 'Semestre':
            startDate = new Date(now.getFullYear(), Math.floor(now.getMonth() / 6) * 6, 1);
            startDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
            break;
        case 'Ano':
            startDate = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
            startDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
            break;
        default:
            startDate = oldestDate;
    }

    const endDate = new Date();
    const filteredData = [];

    let currentDate = new Date(startDate);

    while (currentDate <= endDate) {
        const foundRecord = data.find(record => {
            const recordDate = new Date(record.created_at);
            return (
                recordDate.getFullYear() === currentDate.getFullYear() &&
                recordDate.getMonth() === currentDate.getMonth() &&
                recordDate.getDate() === currentDate.getDate()
            );
        });

        if (foundRecord) {
            filteredData.push({
                created_at: currentDate.toISOString(),
                data: foundRecord
            });
        } else {
            filteredData.push({
                created_at: currentDate.toISOString(),
                data: {
                    temperature: null,
                    humidity: null,
                    // add other sensors as needed
                }
            });
        }

        currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
    }

    return filteredData;
};

In my chart component, I'm trying to map the filtered data:
return (
        <div>
            {/* ... other components */}
            {Object.keys(filteredData).map((key) => (
                <ChartComponent
                    key={key}
                    data={filteredData.map(entry => ({
                        created_at: new Date(entry.created_at),
                        value: entry.data[key]
                    }))}
                    label={key}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

The dates in the filtered data sometimes appear as Invalid Date when rendered in the chart. I suspect there might be an issue with how dates are being processed or filtered. How can I ensure the data is correctly filtered and dates are valid?
